# unable to fully sync geth for use

Tags: go-ethereum

I installed geth, created an account, and made a test payment (0.001). Now i am trying to sync the blockchain. After several hours I reached this point.

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 3886418,
  highestBlock: 3886509,
  knownStates: 44318,
  pulledStates: 18028,
  startingBlock: 3886216
}
> eth.getBlock('latest').number
0
> eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)
0
>
```

I started syncing the blockchain from scratch using `geth --cache=2048 fast` and then when almost all the blocks were loaded i ran `geth --cache=2048`. So, what I can see here when I start geth is this:

```
INFO [06-17|11:11:54] Loaded most recent local header          number=3886284 hash=98a872…a28371 td=3622…722126
INFO [06-17|11:11:54] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0       hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=1717…84
INFO [06-17|11:11:54] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=3886216 hash=f4992e…1782cb td=3621…077687
```

I think I messed up something so I would like to know what I shall do to have the whole system synced and able to send/receive transactions.